# Add rotating keyframes using R? Not letting me rotate my character when I use "Transform" on the side bar

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, transforms, keyframes

So I want my character to spin in place and I tried selecting every individual object/clothes/body part (ctrl+a) basically and using transform but it only rotates one piece of it rather then the entire character.

But when I use R to rotate along the Z-axis it lets me do it, but it wont let me keyframe it? How do I fix this.

[image]

[image: Rotate using R]

[image: only rotates the shirt when using the transform so I can add keyframe here]

Answer (score 1):

When you rotate your object in the 3D view it will rotate around the pivot points you've chosen in the *Transform Pivot Point* panel. You can keyframe. But when you'll play the animation, the transform pivot point won't be taken into account anymore, it's the origin of each object that will be the pivot point of the rotation.

So if you want all your objects to rotate together you have several solutions, like parenting all the objects to one (like the body) and rotate the body only, or parenting all the objects to an empty, and rotate the empty only, or joining all the objects together (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>). Another solution is rigging of course (parenting your object(s) to an armature).

Edit, for your 2nd question:

Maybe create a root bone, parent the bottom spine bone to it, and also the 2 thigh bones, swtich this root to *Euler* instead of *Quaternion*, and type 0° for the first keyframe, 360° for the second:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134933/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-add-rotating-keyframes-using-r-not-letting-me).

Comment: I have the entire model rigged but wouldn't it just take forever since I have to rotate each bone individually?

Comment: So if you want your character to rotate, let's say 180° on the Z axis, why don't you rotate the armature in Pose or Object mode?

Comment: I want it to rotate 360 on the Y-axis but when I do it in pose mode it will only let me rotate it at 180 degress and then any value higher it just doesn't rotate

Comment: maybe create a root bone, parent the bottom spine bone to it, and also the 2 thigh bones, swtich this root to Euler instead of Quaternion, and type 0° for the first keyframe, 360° for the second?

Comment: sorry about that didn't even see the posted reply on here will try it out!