# When rotating the body of my character arms just disconnect entirely, why does this happen?

Tags: mesh, rigging, objects, transforms, keyframes

I have my character rigged, all I want it to do is a 360 degree spin in place. I joined the arms and hands to the body so I can keyframe the rotation but when I did that this happens:

[image]

Same issue whenever I parent the object instead of join

[image]

Comment: Hello Murth, please don't ask twice the same question, also check my answer to your previous question and tell if this is what you want: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258157/add-rotating-keyframes-using-r-not-letting-me-rotate-my-character-when-i-use-t ... And if you share your file, also keep the keyframes so that we understand what you tried to do

Answer (score 0):

Did you try check "connected" on this bone?

[image]